# spawn ls ENOENT when watched file is modified

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning Node.js via the book [Node.js the Right Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937785734). I am trying to run the following example to watch changes to a file called `target.txt` that resides in the the same directory as the `.js` file.

```
"use strict";
const
    fs = require('fs'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    filename = process.argv[2];
if (!filename) {
    throw Error("A file to watch must be specified!");
}
fs.watch(filename, function () {
    let ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', filename]);
    ls.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
});
console.log("Now watching " + filename + " for changes...");
```

I get the following error when I change the text file and save it:

> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: spawn ls ENOENT
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

**Node.js version**: v6.11.0

**IDE**: Visual Studio Code 1.13.1

**OS**: Windows 10 64x

Answer (score 3):

There's no `ls` on Windows, you should use `dir` instead.

However, that's not an executable. To run `.bat` and `.cmd` files you can:

- Spawn `cmd.exe` and pass those files as arguments:

  ```
  require('child_process').spawn('cmd', ['/c', 'dir']);
  ```
- Use `spawn` with the `shell` option set to `true`:

  ```
  require('child_process').spawn('dir', [], { shell: true });
  ```
- Use `exec` instead of `spawn`:

  ```
  require('child_process').exec('dir', (err, stdout, stderr) => { ... });
  ```

For more on that, take a look at [this section in the official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows).

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure I understood you question in the comment correctly, but if you go for the second option, for example, you code will look like this:

```
...

fs.watch(filename, function () {
    let dir = spawn('dir', [filename], { shell: true });

    dir.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
});

...
```

Please, keep in mind you may need to adjust this code slightly. I'm writing all this from memory as I don't have access to a Windows machine right now, so I can't test it myself.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the `require `line. Could you replace the "watch" part with `cmd`? I am getting the TypeError saying "spawn is not a function". Thanks.

Comment: @Disasterkid I'm not sure I understood your question, but please take a look to the edit on the answer.

Comment: This leads to ` let dir = spawn('dir', [filename], { shell: true });
              ^

TypeError: spawn is not a function
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pedram\Documents\Node\hello\watcher-spawn.js:10:15
)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1426:12)`

Comment: @Disasterkid Which node version are you using? It's working for me, at least in macOS with node v6.

Comment: v6.11.0. mentioned also in the question.

Comment: I think the problem is that I amusing Windows. I thought all along that Node.js is not platform-dependent. But apparently I should be more careful.